# Can I execute logcat on the mobile phone itself by issung a command in the shell?

Tags: android, android-logcat

How can I see timestamp in Logcat? Is there any application which shows me the log along with the timestamp? Also, how can I increase the size of the Log in andriod phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several free logcat viewers for Android. I've heard that [aLogCat](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) is pretty good.

EDIT

You can set your preferences in aLogCat to see the time.

Regarding your second question, I found an answer [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/h8Rl4eODXxY/discussion):

> The logs are held by a kernel device; the entries are in /dev/log.
>   The buffer is currently 64KB, and there is no way to change the size
>   on a production device.
>
> The easiest way to keep more of the log is to run "logcat" and send
>   the output to a file.  logcat runs on the device, so you could run it
>   there and redirect it to (say) /sdcard/log.txt.

Comment: But i think aLogCat does not provide timestamp. I want to find start time ad close time of an application. Is there some shell command to view the Log?

Comment: You mean `adb shell`? You can use `logcat -v time`. Use `logcat -?` to see other formatting options. I'm surprised that aLogCat doesn't have an option to see the time stamp.

Comment: I just verified that in aLogCat 2.3 you can see time stamps. From the menu, select Preferences > Format? and select Time. (The default is Brief.)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! There is also a similar application called Xtralogic LogCollecter. It can also send email or message to somebody if required.

Answer (score 4):

To get timestamps: logcat -v time

To run logcat on the device at a shell prompt: logcat